# How to boot from an IDE Drive on a new Mobo

Tags: boot, raid, pata

I currently have a desktop with a mobo that has no IDE slots and i'm trying to boot from an old IDE 32Gb HDD.

So i bought myself a PCI Express card that allows the interface and i was able to access the drive's files through windows 7. The problem is, i need to boot from it and not my default SATA HDD.

I checked boot order, didn't do much and came back to do some research

Then i found out about RAID, now i don't know much about what that is, but from what i understood if i do some kind of configuration related to it, i should be able to select the ide drive as master and boot from it, one problem, i read that the drive will be completely erased so im wondering if anyone knows a way around

Comment: What card did you buy? Many cheap IDE controller cards do not include a BIOS which would permit booting from the connected drives.

Comment: this would be the one : http://www.amazon.co.uk/PCIE-IDE-SATA-CONTROLLER-CARD/dp/B002VA0YPI . During boot, i receive a msg to press Ctrl + J to setup RAID drivers, is that it ?

Comment: i just thought of something, if i use a virtual machine, would i be able to map the physical hard drive to the virtual machine ? or at least copy the files i have to it ?

Comment: That card appears to have a BIOS, so you should be able to select it in the boot menu. Of course, if you're only recovering files, then there should be no need to _boot_ the drive, but just to copy the files...

Comment: You want to run the OS? You could use clonezilla to create an image and mount it virtually. Or use Disk2Vhd http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415

Comment: cool what should i be looking for in the boot menu (to reorder to the top)? UEFI ? actually its not for recovering files, but to run software already installed (copy paste didn't work as i predicted)

Comment: @Logman Yes exactly! i'll check that out